# Attention layer on top of LSTM Autoencoder getting incompatibility error

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder, attention-model

I am deploying a `Bidirectional LSTM Autoencoder`, and am adding `attention layer` on top of that.

Before adding attention layer it is working fine. I got the idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918446/how-to-add-an-attention-mechanism-in-keras) for adding attention layer. 
After adding attention it complains about the dimension incompatibility.

This is my code after adding attention:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(SEQUENCE_LEN, EMBED_SIZE), name="input")
encoded = Bidirectional(LSTM(LATENT_SIZE, return_sequences=True), name="encoder_lstm")(inputs)
attention = Dense(SEQUENCE_LEN, activation='tanh')(encoded)
attention = Flatten()(attention)
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
attention = RepeatVector(SEQUENCE_LEN)(attention)
attention = Permute([2, 1])(attention)
sent_representation = merge([encoded, attention], mode='mul')
sent_representation = Lambda(lambda xin: K.sum(xin, axis=-2), output_shape=(units,))(sent_representation)
autoencoder = Model(inputs, sent_representation)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss='mse')
```

this is the error I got:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
(?, 40, 50)
(?, 40, 40)
Traceback (most recent call last):
(?, 40, 40)
  File "/home/sgnbx/Downloads/projects/LSTM_autoencoder-master/walkingaround.py", line 131, in <module>
    sent_representation = merge([activations, attention], mode='mul')
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 470, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(x)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 411, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_1: expected ndim=2, found ndim=3
```

I have read a couple of post regarding this error, namely: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373774/valueerror-input-0-is-incompatible-with-layer-layer-1-expected-ndim-3-found-n) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635203/input-0-is-incompatible-with-layer-gru-13-expected-ndim-3-found-ndim-2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779433/input-0-is-incompatible-with-layer-flatten-15-expected-min-ndim-3-found-ndim-2).
but they are not the same as my error. Also, Some suggested to make return_sequences=False, but I do not think this is the correct way. Later in the code, it again raises an error if we set it False!

So, I feel like I am doing something wrong, otherwise, why the network should raise the error with the standard architecture.

So my question is that:
what is wrong with this network
and how can I fix it.

I appreciate it if you could explain in detail so I can grasp better or give me some links which talk about the conflict in my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Folks any helpp pleasee

Comment: Did you found solution? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Correct the line below:

```
encoded = Bidirectional(LSTM(LATENT_SIZE, return_sequences=False), name="encoder_lstm")(inputs)
```

Just make the return sequence False.